# Insert Records with Violations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I want to populate 5000 records in the below format to a particular table.

```
Insert into @Table 
(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
Values 
(1,2,3,4,5),
(2,2,3,4,5),
(3,2,3,4,5),
(4,2,3,4,5),
(5,2,3,4,5)
....
....
Up to 1000 rows
```

When I try to execute it. I got a foreign Key violation. I know the reason since one of the value did not exist in its corresponding parent table.

There are few records causing this violation. It's very hard to find those violated rows among the 1000 rows so I want to insert at least the valid records to my target table leaving the violated rows as it is for now.

I am not sure how to perform this. Please suggest me any ideas to do this.

Comment: Which column has foreign key

Comment: Just filter the records before insert which is not part of your parent table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one time thing, then you can do the following:

Drop the FK constraint

```
ALTER TABLE MyTAble
  DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Contstraint
GO
```

Execute INSERT

Find the records with no matching parent id.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable MT WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ParentTable PT WHERE MT.ParentId = PT.ID)
```

DELETE those records or do something else with them.

Recreate the FK constraint.

Comment: `insert into table...SELECT * FROM MyTable MT WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ParentTable PT WHERE MT.ParentId = PT.ID)` This one will save the remaning four steps

Answer (score 0):

Disable the foreign key or fix your data.

Finding the bad data is simple - you can always temporarily insert it into a buffer table and run queries to find which data is missing in the related table.